# How to redraw only the regions of an image that have changed using matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

I have an application where only one row of a 1024x2048 pixel image changes at a rate of 100 times per second. I would like to display and update this image in real time using minimal resources.

However, matplotlib redraws the entire image every time I call the plt.draw() function. This is slow and processor intensive.

Is there a way to redraw only one line at a time?

Comment: Have a look at the `animation` module and "blitting" in matplotlib: https://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html. Depending on your specs, getting 100 frames / second might still be difficult, but 30 Hz and above should definitely be achievable (and quite frankly the human eye won't be able to perceive more frames anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not an expert on matplotlib internals, but I think it cannot be done in that way. Matplotlib was not designed for displaying large changing textures at a high frame rate, it is designed to offer a high level and be very easy to use API for displaying interactive plots.
Internally it is implemented in both python and c++ (for low level and high performance operation), and it uses Tcl / Tk as graphical user interface and widget toolkit (what allows the great cross-platform portability among OSs). 
So, your 1024x2048 matrix has to be transformated several times before it is displayed.

If you do not need the extra features matplotlib gives (as autoscaling, axes, interactive zoom...) and your main goal is speed, I recommend you to use a more focused in performance python library / module for displaying.
There are lots of options: pyopencv, pySDL2...

Comment: Thanks David. I ended up using pygame to blit the portion of the image that needs updating.